# Import Javascript on every page displayed on my Android WebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, webview

Guys i've looked so much for that on the Internet but i didn't find anything relevant. 
My problem is: i want to load several HTML pages on my Android WebView, but for each of those i want to automatically load two or more javascript files (JQuery scripts). How can i do it? I have no possibility of changing the HTML pages.. Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and execute it directly via loadUrl("javascript: your_script )

```
@Override  
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
{  
    webview.loadUrl("javascript: your_script");  
}
```

Comment: I tried it (both loading the url or typing the code), but it doesn't work.. When i click on a link it doesn't show the new page, like if it overloads the HTML page loading with the .js file loading ..

Comment: I mean, i want to import Jquery file in every page, if i override the "loadUrl" method, then the webview will show the JQuery random code..

Comment: Try to execute your code: 
`.loadUrl("javascript: (function(){ your_script })();"); `

Comment: Ok i can use this strategy when i want to execute a function, but i want to import JQuery, so if I load that url the WebView will redirect to the page containing JQuery, which is not what i want to do..